# Variables for each item in a list

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

I have a list of variables named Weapons and I need to make radio buttons for each item in that list, in a weapon switching system. (Using Tkinter)

I tried doing something like this initially:

```
for item in Weapons:
     x = Radiobutton(equipped, text=item['name'], variable=player['weapon'], 
     value=item)
     x.pack()
```

But this failed because all the radio buttons had the same value.
I don't know how many buttons will be needed because it is relative depending on the number of variables inside Weapons.

How can I do this?

Comment: the tag `rpg` says in big letters, `DO NOT USE FOR ROLE PLAYING GAMES`

Comment: what is `player['weapon']`? Is it one of the special tkinter variables?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley player is a dictionary object and weapon is another. it refers to the dictionary object (weapon) that is currently "equipped".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `variable` option must be an instance of one of the special tkinter vars (eg: `StringVar`). You can't use a normal variable or an element in a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Here is use of `exec` to do as asked in comments:

```
n=1
for item in Weapons:
     exec('x'+str(n)+'= Radiobutton(equipped, text=item['name'], variable=player['weapon'], value=item)'
     exec('x'+str(n)+'.pack()'
     n+=1
```

Comment: I want it so that I have
xn = radiobutton(...)
for every n inside Weapons

So if we had 3 items in Weapons, I'd want x1, x2 and x3
This is the only way I can think to attempt this

Comment: Dynamically created variable names are almost never a good idea. Much, _much_ simpler to store them in a dictionary. Regardless, this doesn't address the actual problem, which is related to the value of the `variable` option to the radiobutton.